# Is there a way to simplify this ternary expression?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I have to convert a number from a string to double, but it should be a max of 15. This is my code to do this at the moment:

```
var num = double.Parse(stringNum, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
num = num <= 15 ? num : 15;
```

Is there a way to do this in a single expression?

Comment: `Math.Min(num, 15)` ?

Comment: `var num = Math.Min(double.Parse(stringNum), 15);` But you should probably be calling [double.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) instead. The rest of this is no big deal, whether or not you save a few characters of typing.

Comment: It is possible, but then you have to declare *num* separately with `double num;`  Keep it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
double num = Math.Min(double.Parse(stringNum, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 15);
```